# Using ::before & ::after pseduo elements to move element from left to right

Tags: css, css-selectors, styled-components, pseudo-element

fairly new to using `::before` & `::after` with CSS. Here's what I have so far:

[image]

I have the checkbox that is created by the before & after on the `StyledLabel` - I basically just want to swap the order of the checkbox and the label, so that the checkbox comes after (to the right of) the label?

```css
.wrapper {
  display: inline-flex;
  min-height: 1.5rem;
  padding-left: 1.5rem;
  margin-right: 1 rem;
}

.label {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 0;
 }


 .label:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 4px;
    left: -24px;
    display: block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    pointer-events: none;
    content: "";
    background-color: red;
  }
  
 .label:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 4px;
    left: -24px;
    display: block;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    content: "";
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: 50% 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <label class="label">
    <div class="label-wrapper">In progress</div>
  </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use positioning here, just flexbox and `row-reverse`

```css
.wrapper {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 1.5rem;
  padding-left: 4px;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  border:1px solid grey;
}

.label {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:row-reverse;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.label:before {
    display: block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    pointer-events: none;
    content: "";
    background-color: red;
    margin:0  4px;

  }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <label class="label">
    <div class="label-wrapper">In progress</div>
  </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I have added comments in css to show what you need to change.

```css
.wrapper {
    display: inline-flex;
    min-height: 1.5rem;
    /*padding-left: 1.5rem;*/ /* change this */
    padding-right: 1.5rem; /* to this */
    
    /*margin-right: 1rem;*/ /* change this */
    margin-left: 1rem; /* to this or remove of you will */
}

.label {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.label:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 4px;
    /*left: -24px;*/ /* change this */
    right: -24px; /* to this */
    display: block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    pointer-events: none;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid black; /* added just to show where this element is */
}

.label:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 4px;
    /*left: -24px;*/ /* change this */
    right: -24px; /* to this */
    display: block;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: 50% 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <label class="label">
        <span class="label-wrapper">In progress</span>
    </label>
</div>
```